# Weblogic add-on to serialize web service calls

Tags: web-services, weblogic

Is there a prebuilt tool that would integrate with BEA/Oracle Weblogic 10.0 and trace on a database table each call to a web service exposed by the server?

UPDATE: the goal is **not** to debug the web services (they are working well). The objective is to **trace each call** on a table, using an existing add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a remote debugger, like pretty much any modern IDE.  Attach it to the running application server, breakpoint at the webservice entry point, and follow it through.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an add-on, but you can write a handler (extends from javax.xml.rpc.handler.GenericHandler) where you can write logic to inspect (and manipulate if you so choose) the request, response and the fault (if it occurs).  You can detect things like the remote ip, remote user, etc, and then do whatever you want with them ( i.e. log them to disk, console, db, etc)